# hide_empty = '0' is not working when i use get_categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

for my Theme i want to display all categories including the empty one.
I get only categories that have posts linked. I have tested this behavior with empty category and when i add a post to the empty category then i get the category. I want display empty categories. I make there something wrong?

Here is the code i have tryed:

```
$args = array(
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'taxonomy' => 'category'
);
get_categories($args);
```

I have no idea why this not working.

I also tryed:

```
'hide_empty' => false,
```

and

```
'hide_empty' => 0,
```

Here ist the complete File: [Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtsemfHajE1hqsZxoRbJV55QmdBxwA?e=9knhgJ)

Best regards

Comment: where did you code?

Comment: In whitch IDE? VS Code.

Comment: In the file 'category.php' of my theme. While i'm developing my wordpress theme is this the only one thing what not working.

Comment: did you check the without pass `child_of`

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `gategories` it's get_categories

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
);
get_categories($args);
```

Comment: Sory i misspelled  only in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something went wrong here with my WordPress installation. In a fresh installation it works as expected. I have no idea what's wrong with that.
I apologize for the unnecessary stress.

Answer (score -1):

[image: This is a screenshot of your code]

You use hide_empty value in a string. It's integer required.

Comment: As I wrote in my post above, i also tried the integer value. I tested the values `false`, `'0'` and `0`. None of them had the desired effect.